# Beautifulsoup cerrar conexión

Tags: python, python-requests, beautifulsoup

Estoy tratando de conectarme con Tiktok a través de Beautifulsoup pero la conexión se queda abierta continuamente y no consigo descargar la web.

He probado a añadir un timeout, que evidentemente cierra pero pierdo los datos evidentemente. Hay algún modo de poder enganchar Tiktok con BS?

Este es mi código:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

url = 'https://www.tiktok.com/'
req = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'}, timeout=10)
```

en la línea del requests se queda infinito o si añado el timeout durante el tiempo, pero luego req me dice que no está definido.
También he probado de este otro modo sin resultado.

```
import requests
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()

with eventlet.Timeout(10):
    req = requests.get(url, verify=False)
```

Comment: Para páginas dinámicas o que requieren interacción usa selenium.

Comment: Lo tengo resuelto con Selenium, pero me gustaría entender cómo lo puedo hacer con BS.

Comment: Beautiful soup no permite hacer eso, por eso surgió selenium para permitir esperas o simular la interacción del usuario.